# Проблема с выводом категорий к посту Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

у меня возникала проблема с выводом рубрик для поста.Хочу вывести в виде:
Родитель
-дочка
-дочка

Родитель
-дочка

Мудрю , мудрю.Намудрил что-то похожее, но оно выводит не те категории в которых состоит пост, а все дочерние.

```
<?php
$post = get_post();
$cat = get_the_category($post->ID);
               
foreach ( $cat as $category ) {
    if($category->category_parent == 0){
        echo ("<div class='zagolovok setka'>".$category->name."</div>");
        $categories=get_categories(array( 'parent' => $category->cat_ID ));

        foreach($categories as $qw){ 
            $cat = get_category_link( $qw->term_id );
?>
            <a href="<?php echo $category_link; ?>"><?php echo ($qw->name.","); ?></a>
<?php
                  
        } 
    }
}
?>
```

[image: Скриншот]

Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
$post = get_post();
             
             $catids = wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID, array('fields' => 'ids') );
             
             $cat = wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID, array('fields' => 'all') );
               
             foreach ( $cat as $category ) {
                
                 if($category->parent == 0){
                    
                        echo ("<div class='zagolovok setka'>".$category->name."</div>");
                        
                        $categories = get_categories(array( 'parent' => $category->term_id, 'include' => $catids ));
                                
                        foreach($categories as $qw){ 
                            
                            $cat = get_category_link( $qw->term_id );
                                 ?>
                 
                                 <a href="<?php echo $category_link; ?>"><?php echo ($qw->name.","); ?></a>
                                    <?php
                  
                        } 
                
                }  
                
            }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень  выручили